LOOP AT GROUP BY : Can you pass the data in a group to a separate method as a changing parameter?
When using LOOP AT...GROUP BY... in ABAP, is it possible to pass the data in the group into another method as a changing parameter? To illustrate:
LOOP AT t_tab INTO DATA(s_tab) GROUP BY ( f1  = s_tab-f1 ) ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<g_tab2>).

" Pass data in group <g_tab> into another method to make changes to it

ENDLOOP.

I know I could pass it into a method with export/import and then update the table in a separate loop based on matching keys but I was wondering if there was a simpler way.

A group is a special construct which is part of few statements, it's not a type, so it's not possible to pass a group directly, but instead use these group-processing statements to initialize a variable and pass it as any variable.

you wanna change the original table group by group?

Its totally possible with some workarounds. Have a look at this Sample Code:
CLASS zcl_group_by_group_chang DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC.

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_oo_adt_classrun.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    TYPES: BEGIN OF test_ty,
             col1 TYPE string,
             col2 TYPE string,
             col3 TYPE string,
           END OF test_ty,
           test_tt TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF test_ty WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY col1.
    METHODS
      test_method
        CHANGING
          c_table TYPE test_tt.
ENDCLASS.



CLASS zcl_group_by_group_chang IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD if_oo_adt_classrun~main.
    DATA(test_tab) = VALUE test_tt( ( col1 = '123'
                                      col2 = 'test'
                                      col3 = 'test45' )
                                    ( col1 = '123'
                                      col2 = 'bla'
                                      col3 = 'uff' )
                                    ( col1 = '123'
                                      col2 = 'yey'
                                      col3 = 'no' )
                                    ( col1 = '456'
                                      col2 = 'yes'
                                      col3 = 'titz' )
                                    ( col1 = '456'
                                      col2 = 'blub'
                                      col3 = 'opri' )
                                    ( col1 = 'other'
                                      col2 = 'tate'
                                      col3 = 'tutzi' ) ).
    out->write( data = test_tab name = 'Before changing' ).
    LOOP AT test_tab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<grps>)
                     GROUP BY ( col1 = <grps>-col1 )
                     ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<grp>).
      DATA(group) = VALUE test_tt( FOR <line> IN GROUP <grp> ( CORRESPONDING #( <line> ) ) ).
      me->test_method( CHANGING c_table = group ).

      DATA(index) = 1.
      LOOP AT GROUP <grp> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<member>).
        <member> = group[ index ].
        index += 1.
      ENDLOOP.
    ENDLOOP.
    out->write( cl_abap_char_utilities=>newline )->write( data = test_tab name = 'After changing' ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD test_method.
    LOOP AT c_table ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<row>)."Sample for showing how its done
      CASE <row>-col1.
        WHEN '123'.
          <row>-col3 &&= <row>-col2.
        WHEN '456'.
          <row>-col2 &&= <row>-col3.
        WHEN 'other'.
          <row>-col3 &&= <row>-col1.
      ENDCASE.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.

Just make sure your CHANGING-Method does not change the number of rows or else it will dumb (at least if you reduce the linecount, if you increase it, some line will be omitted). Outside of that, do with it what you want
Console output is this:
Before changing  
COL1   COL2  COL3    
123    test  test45  
123    bla   uff     
123    yey   no      
456    yes   titz    
456    blub  opri    
other  tate  tutzi   

After changing  
COL1   COL2      COL3        
123    test      test45test  
123    bla       uffbla      
123    yey       noyey       
456    yestitz   titz        
456    blubopri  opri        
other  tate      tutziother  

